# Android Navigation SDK for custom maps

Tags: android, mapbox, openstreetmap, graphhopper, turn-by-turn

I am currently entering my final year of college and for my final presentation I want to build an android app for the local zoo in my hometown. In said app I would like to include a map of the area where the zoo is located and add to it the layout of the zoo itself(walking paths, attraction locations etc) so that the users can use the turn-by-turn navigation feature in the zoo itself. So far I have set up the routing using the OSRM backend docker image, and I have the map file itself as an **.osm* file which contains the roads for the zoo. I tested and the routing engine does return directions using roads within the zoo under a GeoJson format.

I am now wondering if it is possible to integrate these directions, from my custom OSRM backend, in the a navigation SDK. From what I have seen so far, most navigation SDKs come with their own routing service, usually exposed as a directions API. Is there a way to bypass the use of that directions API and use my custom backend and map? So far I have tried to work mainly with Mapbox by passing the GeoJson to the *DirectionsResponse.fromJson()* yet the route they display does only go as far as the entrance to the zoo(basically does not take in consideration my custom roads which do not exist in the OpenStreetMap data).

I was thinking to add the zoo layout to the OpenStreetMap but I am not sure of the legislation issues so I would like to keep this project data private.

One thing that is worth mentioning is that I have rendered the OSM file and currently I am hosting it using MapTiler cloud.

If you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. I am a newbie to developing android apps and it is my first time working with geospatial data! Thank you for your patience and understanding!

Comment: Recommendations for tools and libraries are out of scope for StackOverflow. However, take a look at osmdroid for rendering the map. From there it should be possible to call your own navigation service to add a routing feature.

Comment: I completely understand, I ran out of options in my research and thought I could shoot my shot and ask here aswell. Thank you for your suggestion, will look into it! @scai